# Processor friendly way in Java to remove duplicate values from a combined map of 2 maps regardless of key

Tags: java, maps

I have the following 2 Maps in Java.

```
 Map<String, String> carColors = new HashMap<>();
 carColors.put("FirstCar", "Blue");
 carColors.put("SecondCar", "Yellow");
 carColors.put("ThirdCar", "Green");

 Map<String, String> colorsOfCars = new HashMap<>();
 colorsOfCars.put("FirstCar", "Yellow");
 colorsOfCars.put("SecondCar", "Blue");
 colorsOfCars.put("ThirdCar", "Orange");

 //duplicateMaps to avoid concurrency Issues
 Map<String, String> dup1 = new HashMap<>(carColors);
 Map<String, String> dup2 = new HashMap<>(colorsOfCars);
```

I am trying to create a map that removes any matching values regardless of keys, and stores only mismatches. In the example above, the resulting map should only show the thirdCar because it has differing values in both the maps.

I have tried the method below but this gets to be quite Java intensive with large data sets.

```
carColorsMap.entrySet().forEach(carColorEntry -> {
  colorsOfCars.entrySet().forEach(colorCarEntry -> {
     if(carColorEntry.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(colorsOfCars.getValue().toString()){
       dup1.remove(carColorEntry.getKey());
       dup2.remove(colorsOfCarsEntry.getKey()); 
      }
   });
});
```

If there is a more performant way to do this, please share. Thanks

Comment: Not quite clear what you're trying to accomplish. If I see it correctly, you will end up with 2 empty maps. Are you trying to isolate entries that have values that only appear in one of the two maps? What would be the desired result if one of the maps contained the value `"ThirdCar", "Red"` and the other `"ThirdCar", "Green"`?

Comment: The condition is if any values match anywhere in the non-duplicate maps, they should be removed from the duplicate maps, otherwise if there's no match, the duplicate maps do not remove those entries. In the case of thirdCar with different values, the duplicate maps would not remove said entries

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following approach can help to reduce the complexity of running two loops.

```
        // Create a set of unique values from both maps
        Set<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>(dup1.values());
        uniqueValues.addAll(dup2.values());

        // Remove entries with values found more than once
        uniqueValues.forEach(value -> {
                dup1.values().removeIf(val -> val.equals(value));
                dup2.values().removeIf(val -> val.equals(value));
        });
```

Comment: This will remove all entries, always. Not only those that exists in both tables. Using `Set::retainAll` instead of `Set::addAll` would do the job a bit better.